# On page load, will mypic.jpg get downloaded by the browser?

Tags: html, css

```css
#test1 {
    display: none;
}
#test2 {
    background-image: url('mypic.jpg');
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">
    <span id="test2"></span>
</div>
```

Please provide the reason why yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

In the above case, it won't.

Normally if you make the CSS property as

```
display: none
```

the browser will still download it as there might be a chance of dynamically changing it in DOM. But still, if you wish that, your image should not be downloaded then, use your images or at least the ones that you intend to hide, as background images.

> Background images don’t get loaded if the element is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

All resources will be downloaded to user computer, so **yes, it will**.

Browser will not re-download resource if it already has copy of it in local cache and it's content not changed and time not expired.